# Using webpack with an existing PHP and JS project

Tags: php, jquery, css, node.js, webpack

I have an existing PHP project with jquery and bootstrap, not using any front-end framework.

I am trying to use webpack module bundler in order to create a single entry point for my project resources, manage js dependencies with node js package manager, run tasks as minify js css, image re-size...etc. And improve the browser loading time required to load a single page.

I came across the webpack tutorials and got to install it and install its dev-server, but the problem is that I am not able to understand how I will convert all my current js scripts and css links in the project (where I have a lot of jquery and CSS libraries used to provide multiple features in the project) to use webpack.

**Do I have to rewrite all my JS and CSS files in a way that suits webpack? How do I make a successful migration?**

**Besides, I am not able to run my current php application on the webpack dev-server, is it meant to run there in the first place? It is only listing the directories of the project in the meantime.**

I have created a test `index.js` file and used the following webpack configuration:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports =
{
    entry: [
        './public/js/index.js',
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080'
    ],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "public/dist/js"),
        publicPath : "http://localhost:8080/my_proj/public/dist/js",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }

};
```

I added the `bundle.js` to my script loads just for testing as follows hoping that the application will run on the webpack dev-server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/dist/js/bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.migrate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**Please help me understand the concept here and how can I make this migration successfully?**

Comment: I'm afraid the sheer scope of your question is too broad to be answered in a single SO answer. If you actually want to do non-basic stuff (e.g. minifying things) you should get a grasp of how webpack concepts work. That will take a fair amount of time, but I think it's worth it.
I can recommend the SurviveJS webpack tutorial, it's by written by a guy from the webpack core team and got me pretty far. https://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/

Comment: Regarding your questions: No, your PHP application will not run on a webpack dev server since that's just a simple Node.js server serving only static files. No, you most likely won't have to rewrite any of your JavaScript files except some rare edge cases. (e.g. if you have used global variables by defining them with `var` in the global scope they won't be global anymore.) If your existing JS is `use strict` compliant, you should probably be fine.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

First, to answer your smaller questions:

- No, you're not supposed to run your PHP application through a webpack dev server. Explained in the *Live Reloading* section below.
- No, you won't have to rewrite your assets. Probably. See the *CSS* and *Edge Cases* sections below.

---

*Disclaimer:* I'll only take on a small fraction of your question. Its scope is just way too broad to be packed into just one StackOverflow answer.

I will only get in touch with

- setting up a development and a production environment for webpack
- bundling your first JavaScript

which should give you a foundation to build on.

I'll also mention some things you may want to add and link according resources to read through.

So, let's go.

### Requirements

I assume you have Node.js and npm installed on your machine and roughly know how to use them.

I also assume you have `webpack` and `webpack-cli` installed as (dev) dependencies of your project (not just globally):

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
```

> **Update:** Earlier versions of this answer did not require installing `webpack-cli`. As of version 4 (February 2018), webpack's CLI resides in its own package, hence the additional required package.

### Set up development and a production workflow

You usually want to do stuff differently in development than in production (minifying in production, live-reloading in development, ...)

To achieve that, we'll want to split up our configuration files.

#### Prepare the directory structure

Let's agree to ignore the webpack config from your question. We'll start all over, we'd have to change almost everything anyway.

First, create a `build` folder inside your project root. Build-related stuff will go there, since we don't want to pollute your project's root folder with config files. (You're free to name this folder differently, but keep track of that during this tutorial.)

Create a `config.base.js`,  a `config.production.js` and a `config.development.js` file inside that folder.

Great, we have config files for two build chains now. The configurations are still empty though, so let's now fill them with some basic logic.

#### Install `webpack-merge`

But first, we'll need to install `webpack-merge`.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-merge
```

This package allows us to deeply merge multiple webpack configurations. We want to use it to create webpack configurations depending on our current environment.

#### Adjust your configuration

Now adjust your `build/config.base.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // We'll place webpack configuration for all environments here
}
```

The file does obviously just export an empty object right now, but we'll need that for the following steps.

Put this code in your `build/config.production.js`:

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')

module.exports = merge(require('./config.base.js'), {
  mode: 'production'
  
  // We'll place webpack configuration for production environment here
})
```

And almost the same code goes into your `build/config.development.js`:

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')

module.exports = merge(require('./config.base.js'), {
  mode: 'development',
  watch: true
  
  // All webpack configuration for development environment will go here
})
```

I guess it's pretty intuitive what this does:

Using webpack with the `config.development.js` configuration will fetch the common configuration and merge its own config declaration in.

> **Update:** The `mode` option in the above config files was added in webpack 4 (released February 2018). It sets [a bunch of sensible defaults](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-mode-and-optimization-5423a6bc597a) for development and production bundles.

Now running the process would look like this from the command line:

```
npx webpack --config build/config.development.js

# If the above doesn't work, you probably have an older version of npm (< 5.1) installed
# While npx is a really great tool, you can of course still call the path of the webpack executable manually:

node_modules/.bin/webpack --config build/config.development.js
```

...and vice versa for the `production` environment.

That command is rather clunky to use, but no worries, we'll address that later.

#### Make some helper files

There are information we'll be wanting to centralize to make them easily exchangeable. File paths are such a thing. So let's extract them.

Create a `paths.js` in your `build` folder and have it export some paths we'll want to use later:

```js
const path = require('path')

// I'm really just guessing your project's folder structure from reading your question,
// you might want to adjust this whole section
module.exports = {
  // The base path of your source files, especially of your index.js
  SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public'),

  // The path to put the generated bundle(s)
  DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'dist'),

  /*
  This is your public path.
  If you're running your app at http://example.com and I got your DIST folder right,
  it'll simply be "/dist".
  But if you're running it locally at http://localhost/my/app, it will be "/my/app/dist".
  
  That means you should probably *not* hardcode that path here but write it to a
  machine-related config file. (If you don't already have something like that,
  google for "dotenv" or something similar.)
  */
  ASSETS: '/dist'
}
```

#### Create aliases

As mentioned above, we could technically run our build chain in `development` mode like this:

```
npx webpack --config build/config.development.js
```

That's an uncomfortably verbose command though, so let's change that.

It's way more convenient to run your build process via `npm` scripts. Add one script per environment to your `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --config build/config.development.js",
    "prod": "webpack --config build/config.production.js"
  }
}
```

Now you can run your build chains with `npm run dev` resp. `npm run prod` – which is much easier to memorize and faster to type.

...as soon as there'es anything to build, of course.

### Bundle JavaScript

Okay, that was actually a fair amount of work without achieving too much so far.

So let's start with something more exciting: We'll define a JavaScript entry point.

#### Define an entry point

Put the following code into your `build/config.base.js` (replacing the existing code entirely):

```
const path = require('path')
const { SRC, DIST, ASSETS } = require('./paths')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    scripts: path.resolve(SRC, 'js', 'index.js')
  },
  output: {
    // Put all the bundled stuff in your dist folder
    path: DIST,

    // Our single entry point from above will be named "scripts.js"
    filename: '[name].js',

    // The output path as seen from the domain we're visiting in the browser
    publicPath: ASSETS
  }
}
```

#### Create the JavaScript file

The above configuration expects an `index.js` to live in your `SRC/js` folder (as defined in the `build/paths.js`).

Let's create that file with the following content:

```
import './jquery.min.js'
import './jquery.migrate.js'
import './jquery.bxslider.min.js'
import './jquery.appear.js'
import './jquery.countTo.js'
import './bootstrap.js'
```

As you can see, the `index.js` just imports all of the files you want to use.

If you now run

```
npm run prod
```

from your terminal, a `scripts.js` file will be created in your `DIST` folder. You can include that into your markup with a plain ol' `<script>` tag.

Congratulations, you've got a working webpack setup!

### Dive deeper

This mini-tutorial really just scraped the surface of what you can do with webpack. It gives you a pretty solid foundation for your configuration which you now can fill with whatever you need. And that will actually be quite a lot of stuff.

I'll list a few more things you may want to enhance, with some links to read through.

#### webpack Concepts

If you want to use webpack, it can be hard to do so if you don't know about its underlying concepts. [Juho Vepsäläinen](https://github.com/bebraw) created a great guide on getting started with webpack which helped me a whole lot. He's also a webpack core contributor so you can be sure he knows what he's talking about.

Especially *loaders* are a concept you'll really *need* to know.

Many of the hints on this list are also explained there.

Read more: [SurviveJS – webpack tutorial](https://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/)

#### Code Splitting

It does what the name's saying: You might not want to pack all your JavaScript into one bulky output file.

It's a job webpack does for you to split off parts of your bundle which you only need on certain pages of your application.

Also, depending on how frequently you're working on your project's JavaScript, it might be a good idea to split off third party code from your bundle for caching purposes.

Read more: [webpack Documentation – Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)

#### Caching

You may want to enhance your site's caching behaviour by adding a hash to your bundled file names which depends on their content. This will create (for example) a `script.31aa1d3cad014475a618.js` instead of a `scripts.js`.

That file can then be cached indefinitely because as soon as its contents change, the file name will change as well.

Your PHP code might then use the `webpack-manifest-plugin` to gain access to the generated file names.

Read more:

- [Immutable Caching](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/01/using-immutable-caching-to-speed-up-the-web/) on how to cache your bundles forever
- [webpack Documentation – `chunkhash`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename) on how to enrich your bundle file names with hashes
- [`webpack-manifest-plugin`](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) on how to generate a `manifest.json` containing the file names of your current bundle

#### Transpiling

In case you want to use modern ES2015 code in your site's JavaScript (and are targeting non-evergreen browsers), you'll want to transpile them down to regular ES5. (If the term "ES2015" does not make any sense to you, you're most likely not using it and can ignore this paragraph.)

Read more: [`babel-loader` – A loader that runs Babel on your scripts](https://npmjs.com/package/babel-loader)

#### CSS

There are webpack loaders for CSS. And Sass. And PostCSS. Whatever you need.

And since you're probably not planning to include your CSS via `<script>` tags, get to know the *Extract Text Plugin* to generate actual `.css` files.

> **Update:** The *Extract Text Plugin* is very established. However, it's actually a kind of hack: It generates `.css` files even though webpack only knows JavaScript as its target language.
>
> However, this is no longer true as of webpack 4. There's now a system to define arbitrary module types, including CSS.
>
> Long story short: [Expect native CSS support in webpack to replace *Extract Text Plugin* some time soon](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-released-today-6cdb994702d4#d179).

##### Hint: Paths

I'll mention this because this was a real pain point for me until I realized how webpack works here:

Be aware that webpack will recognize your `url(...)` statements and try to resolve them *relative to your source files*.

This means, your source file `public/css/main.css`:

```
body {
  background: url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

if your output path is `public/dist/css/bundle.css`, will be transformed to:

```
body {
  background: url('../../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

Read more:

- [style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader) and [css-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader) – you'll hands down need those.
- [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

#### Minifying

> **Update:** Since webpack 4 was released in February 2018, this section is rather obsolete. Setting the new `mode` option to `"production"` now automatically applies JavaScript minification.

There is a [Terser](https://github.com/terser-js/terser) plugin for webpack to minify your JavaScript. Minifying CSS is a feature already builtin to the `css-loader` plugin mentioned above.

Read more: [Terser webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-webpack-plugin)

#### Image Optimization

webpack is a bundler, not a task runner. Thus, image optimization is not a genuine webpack task. You'd probably be better off using an actual task runner or just defining some `npm` scripts for this.

This does not mean webpack is not capable of doing this. There are plugins for pretty much everything.

Read more:

- [imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin) can minify images pretty nicely on its own.
- [imagemin-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webpack-plugin) will integrate that process into your webpack build chain.

#### Live Reloading

Your problems with live reloading have a pretty simple cause: a webpack dev server is just a simple Node.js server serving only static files.

For you're case, `webpack-dev-server` probably is the wrong tool at all. Try `webpack-livereload-plugin` instead for a live reloader that you can just include via `<script>` tag.

Read more: [`webpack-livereload-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-livereload-plugin)

#### Source Maps

> **Update:** As of webpack 4 (released in February 2018), source maps are automatically generated when the new `mode` option is set to `"development"`.

By all means, use source maps. They'll make your work with bundles so much easier you'll want to cry.

Read more: [webpack Documentation – Source Maps](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#source-maps)

#### Edge Cases

Usually, all your existing scripts you'll process with webpack should be running just fine.

The only exception that comes to my mind right now would be regarding global entities.

Look at the following code:

```
function myFunc () {
  console.log('I exist!')
}
```

This code in a plain JavaScript file would make `myFunc` available everywhere in your JS code. But since webpack bundle code is wrapped inside callback functions (and thus leaving the global scope), there won't be any access to that function anymore.

Third party libraries should not be a problem there, they usually assign their globals to the `window` object directly, but if you've already written JS code in your project, you should be aware of that.

#### Automate!

You'll want to automate as much of your workflow as possible.

Consider running `npm run prod` via a git hook before pushing / after pulling.

Comment: I know I'm not suppose to use comments to say thanks but I really appreciate you typing this out! I have no idea how webpack works but after the info you gave and the resources you linked I feel like I have a jumping off point to learn more and I'm confident I'll be able to figure it out, so thanks for taking the time to help out!

Comment: Looks awesome - I haven't followed the links to other resource, yet, but I promise I will! But what I find puzzling is how I can use this approach with my existing Zend Framework project. It mostly uses css and javascript via <style> and <script> tags within .phtml files; and of course <img> tags. So it would seem I'd need something to extract and modify the src= attributes from those tags. Since they could appear within embedded php code, it's not clear an html parser would work. I was thinking of writing a gawk script, but I'd think that loses (continued)

Comment: all the smart stuff like concatenation, minification, and hashed-file-content names for cache-busting. It seems that everything is based on parsing javascript, but my own javascript has virtually no references to css files or other javascript files. So I think I'm missing something really fundamental. Are the applications using webpack generally pure javascript using node as their webserver?

Comment: Not at all, webpack's used by the asset bundlers of popular PHP frameworks like Laravel ("Mix") or Symfony ("Assetic"). I think the fact that webpack's so node-centric is just because its roots are in parsing just JavaScript and it's pretty natural to write JS-parsing stuff in JS itself.

Comment: Your JS not having references to other files is usually only partially true: not having references to CSS files is pretty usual, you'll normally use CSS as separate entry points in your bundling process. References to other files however are usually established inderectly, by referencing global variables (like the $ in jQuery). That's also completely natural due to the lack of any official module system.

Comment: In the live reloading section. Author recommended `webpack-livereload-plugin` to attain live reloading. I tried it but find many problems using it. I then use `browser-sync` and `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` instead, and it works very well. So I recommend to use `browser-sync` to achieve live reloading functionality.

Comment: What I also find useful is to add a so called `"clean": "rimraf dist/"` or just `"clean": "rm -rf dist"` script and call `npm run clean` right before the `npm run dev` and `npm run prod`. So you could simply have a script like this `"cprod": "npm run clean && npm run prod"`. Then simply run `npm run cprod`. It will first clean your "dist" folder, and then build it from scratch. This make sure that any none used files are removed from the directory. Especially useful when playing around with your webpack config to try new things out.

Comment: @RensTillmann There's even a webpack plugin that does this automatically for you. Just include it in the production build chain and you're good to go: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cleanup-plugin

Comment: @Loilo, didn't know about this plugin, thanks for sharing! This will make life even more easy! :)

Comment: @Loilo, didn't work for deleting folders, I will stick to my method for now works just as good I guess.

Comment: @sootsnoot I'm in the same situation you commented about Zend Framework. Have you reached something interesting using it with Zend?

Comment: Sorry, @Fantasmic - I really haven't done anything further with this, and don't have a believable schedule for doing so. Our website stays up and running 24x7, and is more or less bug-free; making changes to add urgently needed functionality improvements and add support for revenue far outweigh the urgency of cool rewrites with improved technology.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the existing vue-templates and and the answer from @Loilo I made a vue template you can install with `vue-cli`. This template jumpstarts you for a vue application you can extend with or integrate in you existing environment.

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init delcon/webpack-simple my-project
cd my-project
npm install
```

**devwatch:**

This template has an additional run devwatch option that watches for filechanges instead of using the webpack-dev-server. This makes it usable for any existing webserver enviroment.

```
npm run devwatch
```

**dev:**

to run it with the default webpack-dev-server, remove `<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` in `index.html`:

```
npm run dev
```

**build:**

to build your project for production:

```
npm run build
```