# Using webpack in a ZF3 MVC application to bundle the frontend JS files

Tags: javascript, webpack, zend-framework3

I am using ZF3 MVC and I want to also use Webpack to bundle and manage dependencies in my frontend Javascript.

I looked at this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43436754/5583348) to a similar question but it does not address specifically ZF3 MVC apps.

In my app, some pages have AngularJS fontends, some have React (I am transitioning to React) and most have at least Bootstrap.  And the pages that have more extensive frontends, also require packages like TinyMCE.

Since not all the rendered pages of a ZF3 application need the same frontend JS, how do you create multiple bundles so that each rendered page can have its own bundle of scripts?

It would not be efficient to have "one size fits all" frontend that loads everything that you would ever need in your frontend.

How do you easily keep track of which bundles needs to be loaded by which view template?

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of expirementing and developed two packages that answered my problem.

- [php-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/visto9259/php-webpack-plugin), a Webpack plugin that generates a PHP manifest of entry points and corresponding bundles
- [zend-webpack](https://github.com/visto9259/zend-webpack), a ZF3 module to consume the manifest and map bundles to routes using a route listener and a view helper to add the script tags to the `<head>`of the rendered page.

I also wrote the following [guide](https://visto9259.github.io/docs/zend-webpack-guide-getting-started) that explains how to use them.

I hope this can be useful to others.