# Webpack usage newbie

Tags: php, file, config

I have read a lot of documentation. But I am still puzzling to start creating 1 big file.

My main page look likes the following (4Mb of script files).
These includes are sitting in a webpage.php file. I am able to extract each file name with a PHP script
So my idea is generating a webpack config file. Is this indeed the way to go and how will the file look like (with 2 file names I have enough to compile the rest my self :-).
My folder structure is like this: The pciture below.
I have a bit of two roots one is called ezm (where the file webpage.php resides). The main root holds login.php and some plain (read wo a long list of js files).
Must I make a folder ezm_distr and ezm_dev? Given that I have development and production.

Your help is welcomed with open arms!!! Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/css/swipe_delete.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/css/themes/b4y.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/css/common.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/css/risk_address.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/js/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/js/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/js/jonthornton-jquery-timepicker-f670370/jquery.timepicker.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="./include/js/jquery/jquery321-min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./include/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!=============================== jq widgets framework=================================>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxcore_full.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxcombobox.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxnumberinput.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>

<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxgrid_full.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxdata.export.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.export.js"></script>

<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
<!============================================================================>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/config.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/libv13.js<?php echo "?v=$ts\""; ?>"></script>

<script src="./include/js/jquery.price_format.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="./include/date_mask/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jQuery-Mask-Plugin-master/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<script src="./include/js/querystring.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jquery.md5.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/jquery_punch/jquery_punch.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/accounting.min.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/cl_querystring_target.js"></script>

<script src="./include/js/jonthornton-jquery-timepicker-f670370/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/cl_ezpage15.js<?php echo "?v=$ts\""; ?>></script>

<script src="./include/js/cl_filterable.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/fileupload12.js"></script>
<script src="./include/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<style>
  .ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb > img:first-child,
  .ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb > .ui-btn > img:first-child,
  .ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb .ui-li-thumb {
      left: 1px;
      top: 1px;
      max-height: 90px;
      max-width: 250px;
  }
  .ui-listview > .ui-li-has-thumb > .ui-btn,
  .ui-listview > .ui-li-static.ui-li-has-thumb {
      min-height: 0;
      padding: .9em 1em .9em 55px;
  }

  .ui-state-disabled {
      opacity: 0.7;
  }
  .ui-btn.my-tooltip-btn,
  .ui-btn.my-tooltip-btn:hover,
  .ui-btn.my-tooltip-btn:active {
      background: none;
      border: 0;
  }
  .ezli_sel {
      color:blue !important;
  }
  .asso_href_rel_leg {
      color:green !important;
  }
  .asso_href {
      float :left;
      color:green !important;
  }
  .asso_href_straight {
      float :left;
      color:green !important;
  }

  pre,code{font-family:monospace; }

  /* Left transition */
  li.left {
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 250ms ease;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100 % );
      -moz-transition:-moz-transform 250ms ease;
      -moz-transform: translateX(-100 % );
      -o-transition:-o-transform 250ms ease;
      -o-transform: translateX(-100 % );
      transition: transform 250ms ease;
      transform: translateX(-100 % );
  }
  /* Right transition */
  li.right {
      -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 250ms ease;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100 % );
      -moz-transition:-moz-transform 250ms ease;
      -moz-transform: translateX(100 % );
      -o-transition:-o-transform 250ms ease;
      -o-transform: translateX(100 % );
      transition: transform 250ms ease;
      transform: translateX(100 % );
  }
  /* Border bottom for the previous button during the transition*/
  li.left a.ui-btn,
  li.right a.ui-btn {
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-left-width: 1px;
      border-right-width: 1px;
  }
  li a.ui-btn.border-bottom {
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
  }
  /* Hide the delete button on touch devices */
  ul.touch li.ui-li-has-alt a.delete {
      display: none;
  }
  ul.touch li.ui-li-has-alt a.ui-btn {
      margin-right:0;
  }
  /* Styling for the popup */
  #confirm p {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: inherit;
      margin-bottom: .75em;
  }
  .ui-content {
      margin-left :0.75em;
  }
  .ui-select .ui-btn select{
      font-size: 50px !important;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./include/css/table_browse.css">
```

John

Comment: See also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436754/using-webpack-with-an-existing-php-and-js-project Try to fiddle this out.

Comment: I swithced to the sublime codeigniter library carabiner! Straight forward with good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

My compressed code compiled with php tool carabiner is not running :-(