# Importing node modules for browser usecase

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

> Let me preface this with the following. I'm very new to everything you read about here.

I'm trying to use a JavaScript package manager - yarn.
Bundling the dependencies - Webpack seems to be the way.
Using JavaScript modules rather than classic JavaScript scripts.

I've got a PHP project that doesn't use a front-end framework per-se. It's a custom "framework" where each `.php` file (contains primarily HTML) and has an accompanying `.js` file. For example, If I have a home page. I have `Home.php` and `Home.js` files.

I have JS dependencies and I'm using `yarn` as a package manager for it which downloads dependencies in the `node_modules` folder. I intend to refer the JS resources directly from this folder without bundling them, or at least until I figure out Webpack.

So in the beginning of the `home.php` file I include the dependencies w.r.t the `node_modules` folder. What I want to do is the following: I want to utilize/use the dependencies directly.  I'll take the example of `@eonasdan/tempus-dominus` package. I'm using VSCode and I get an auto import when I create an instance of its class.

```
import { TempusDominus } from "../../node_modules/@eonasdan/tempus-dominus/types/tempus-dominus";

let tmp = new TempusDominus();
```

This because I have a `jsconfig.json` file with mode as ES6. I need this for relative imports. One, I am getting the types import which I believe is used for typescript. I'm not sure about this. This is very new to me.

Second, when I open the page in the browser, it fails (naturally) since it's not giving the extension, which can be solved from the settings of VSCode to add the extension. But when I do enable it, it adds the extension `.js` where the file is a `*.d.ts` file.

Which leads me to believe there is something wrong with my settings.

I have been scratching my head for a long time now. I could not get anywhere with this. Coming to Webpack, the issue with using Webpack for me is the following: Since I have an accompanying js file for each php file, how do I go about bundling them?

Do I even bundle each of those files or leave them to be?

I have referred to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43436754/5723098) to understand a bit better regarding Webpack. But couldn't really understand how to handle my JS files.

EDIT:
The JS files that are part of the project have been included as type "text/javascript" which make the files incredibly large for complex pages. I would like to break it down into multiple files, hence the use of type "module". With this change however, I would also like to use the autocomplete and import statements by referencing the node_modules. From what I understand so far, the only way to use the node_modules would be then to actually bundle each of my .js files individually. The other option being, bundling the node modules and using the window.* objects that the modules attach to.

EDIT 2:
webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./cp/dependencies.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "cp", "dist"),
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "Reno",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

dependencies.js

```js
//JS dependencies
import "./../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery";
import "./../node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper";
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";
import "./../node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full";
import "./../node_modules/@eonasdan/tempus-dominus/dist/js/tempus-dominus";
import "./../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables";
import "./../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart";
import "./plugins/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte";
import "./plugins/summernote/summernote-lite";

//Stylesheet dependencies
import "./media/fonts/exo/exofont.css";
import "./media/fonts/SourceSansPro/ssp.css";
import "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "./../node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css";
import "./../node_modules/select2-bootstrap-5-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.css";
import "./../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "./../node_modules/@eonasdan/tempus-dominus/dist/css/tempus-dominus.css";
import "./../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css";
import "./plugins/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.css";
import "./plugins/summernote/summernote-lite.min.css";
```

Comment: You would probably need to configure each of those (e.g.) `Home.js`es to be a Webpack entrypoint, so you'd end up with several bundles (which would then contain dependencies too). As an aside, your imports should never contain `../../node_modules/` or similar; resolving `node_modules` is done by the bundler.

Comment: Oh, so you suggest not to use node_modules directly? 
Why is that though? 
What if I decide to just use npm/yarn only as a dependency manager?
Do I just bundle the dependencies as explained in the link in the original post? 
Have an index.js which requires just the dependencies.
Include the bundle only and then keep my JS files as is?
Without using the node modules but the global variables available?

Comment: I'm saying your import statement should not mention `node_modules` because they don't need to. I'm not sure what your end goal here is – if you just want to use some packages, chances are they already have UMD builds which you can include using `<script>`, and they will export the library to your global scope, and you can go ahead and use it without bundling. You can also set up webpack to just export things as UMD, so you would then do `<script src="my-bundle.js">` and use your separate JS files as-is.

Comment: The JS files that are part of the project have been included as type "text/javascript" which make the files incredibly large for complex pages. I would like to break it down into multiple files, hence the use of type "module". With this change however, I would also like to use the autocomplete and import statements by referencing the node_modules. From what I understand so far, the only way to use the node_modules would be then to actually bundle each of my .js files individually. The other option being, bundling the node modules and using the window.* objects that the modules attach to. Yes?

Comment: Okay, if also being able to break up the single JS files to modules, it does then sound like you want to just bundle each of the different views' (e.g. `Home`) JS files as separate entrypoints (or just separately), so you can split them up into modules _and_ use other dependencies in them.

Comment: In regards to just bundling the js files separately and using my js files as is. I couldn't do that @AKX. I did put targetlibrary as umd. Eventhough the scripts and stylesheets are being bundled properly, none of the exports are to the window. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'll put my webpack config up here in a minute